# File Search in LINUX

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

I have two files with `FILE1` containing lots of lines and `FILE2` with *KEY VALUE* parms. I need to compare `FILE2` with `FILE1` and if there is match the corresponding word in `FILE1` should be replace with next column in `FILE2`.

Example:

FILE1:

```
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
PARM1
value:PARM2
PARM3
somyaml_PARM4
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->
```

FILE2:

```
PARM1 mmddyy
PARM2 hhmmss
PARM3 awsid
PARM4 cc
```

So for every match from `FILE2` in `FILE1`, the corresponding word in FILE1 should be replace with 2nd column in `FILE2`. So the desired output should like:

```
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
**mmddyy**
value:**hhmmss**
**awsid**
somyaml_**cc**
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->
```

with the help of other community i was able to run below command but it works only if the SEARCH criteria is at the start of the line

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{k[$1]=$2;}
    NR!=FNR{if($1 in k){$0=k[$1]};print}
' file2 file1
```

Comment: Please format your question properly. Hint: try the `{}` button.

Comment: Also note that you need a YAML parser because neither of the Regex Based shell tools are appropriate to manipulate complex data structures such as YAML, JSON, XML/HTML/SGML… Or choose a language with libraries to parse such as Python, Ruby, Perl…

Comment: To do what's shown in your example is trivial. To do what I think you'd want if some of your PARMs could be subset of other PARMs (e.g. PARM2 was in file2 but PARM20 was in file1) or contained regexp metachars, or the 2nd fields from PARM2 contained `&` or other backreference strings would be much harder. So if any of that can happen then instead of just posting the one trivial sunny-day case where everything is just unique, unrelated strings of alphanumeric characters, [edit] your question to provide an example that would be a a real test of a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want even if you have PARM values that are subsets of other PARM values, or PARMs that contain regexp metachars or replacement strings that contain backreferences or recursive definitions where PARM1 is mapped to PARM2 and PARM2 to PARM1. If file2 defines a mapping of one PARM to another then this just does the mappings in longest-first order. It uses GNU awk for sorted_in so we can visit the PARMs in longest-first order to handle subsets correctly - if you don't have GNU awk then do the sort of file2 outside of the awk script.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
}
NR==FNR {
    map[$1] = $2
    len[$1] = length($1)
    next
}
{
    for ( old in len ) {
        new = map[old]
        head = ""
        tail = $0
        while ( s=index(tail,old) ) {
            head = head substr($0,1,s-1) new
            tail = substr(tail,s+len[old])
        }
        $0 = head tail
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
mmddyy
value:hhmmss
awsid
somyaml_cc
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->
```

The example provided in the question isn't good though as it only covers the most basic sunny day case where all strings in file2 are unique and comprised of only alphanumeric characters. A better test uses regexp metachars in the first string, strings that are subsets of other strings, and backreference metachars in the replacement strings, e.g.:

```
$ head file1 file2
==> file1 <==
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
A.B
value:A.BX
PARM3
somyaml_PARM4
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->

==> file2 <==
A.B mmddyy
A.BX hhmmss
PARM3 a\1b&c
PARM4 cc
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
mmddyy
value:hhmmss
a\1b&c
somyaml_cc
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->
```

That's still missing cases to consider, e.g. where file2 contains recursive mappings or even just one-off mappings from one "PARM" string to another:

```
$ head file1 file2
==> file1 <==
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
PARM1
value:PARM2
PARM3
somyaml_PARM4
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->

==> file2 <==
PARM1 mmddyy
PARM2 hhmmss
PARM3 PARM4
PARM4 PARM3
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
mmddyy
value:hhmmss
PARM4
somyaml_PARM4
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->
```

but that's not discussed in the question so I don't know if that's the expected output or not and, if not, what the expected output WOULD be and why - update the question if you need to handle that or any of the other non-trivial cases differently.